# What user does Visual Studio 2008 use when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-7

I have a web application that accesses Windows resources on another server.  The code is fine and when I run it through the debugger it's able to see the remote resources without any difficulty, but when I put the code into IIS it fails with ACCESS_DENIED.  I'm trying to see what rights I need to give to the web application.

Difficulty:  We're a startup and don't have a domain, so no domain admin accounts.  This is why I'm trying to find out how VS2008 runs when it's in debug mode, since however that runs is one way that I know the security works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running the site using the internal web server in VS 2008 the code runs as you, the developer.

Comment: Are you sure about this?  I had assumed this as well so I configured the IIS site to run with my account as well and I still get ACCESS_DENIED.

Comment: Yes. See "Security Context for the ASP.NET Development Server" in this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5(VS.80).aspx

It will tell you how to solve the exact problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

When using IIS, you need to ensure 'IIS_IUSRS' user has Access Rights to the Website Folder.
You can do that from the 'Security' tab for that folder